# Error creating vm in its own cloud service

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

Trying to create iaas vms using rest api in central us south central us and west us regions.

The vms are in their own cloud service. Creating one vm at a time.

Its been 3 -4 hours and gui shows deployment is ongoing.

Error message from operation id is as follows:

Failed409`ConflictEr
ror`Windows Azure is currently performing an operation on this de
ployment that requires exclusive access.

The strange part is that using powershell or the gui I can create vms successfully.

Additional info:
I am using the Create VM Deployment API.

The workflow to create a vm is :

1) Create cloudservice

2) Create vm in the above cloud service using Create VM Deployment API. Im using Production slot.

I did the following test:

1) Create cloud service using azure gui - success

2) Create vm using curl command. The output of curl has the request id. Run another curl command to get the status of creating vm in cloudservice created in step 1.

3) The curl command to get operation status showed Inprogress a few times and then it errors out with conflict error.

4) Additionally, I checked the gui and its been almost 30 mins and no sign of vm creation. The Cloud service shows "Deployment in progress"

```
C:\Users\gardam\preprodmgmtcert>curl -D - -E preprodazcert.pem -H "x-ms-version:
 2014-10-01" -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -X POST -d @makevm.xml https://m
anagement.core.windows.net/<subscriptionid>/services/hosteds
ervices/testvmcs/deployments
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 0
Server: 1.0.6198.167 (rd_rdfe_stable.141203-1417) Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-servedbyregion: ussouth2
x-ms-request-id: 997a9dadcac53e43a926b36481fc8f53
Date: Mon, 08 Dec 2014 01:47:47 GMT


C:\Users\gardam\preprodmgmtcert>curl -D - -E preprodazcert.pem -H "x-ms-version:
 2014-10-01" https://management.core.windows.net/04dc0d13-8d80-4781-b4b9-603708c
e871c/operations/997a9dadcac53e43a926b36481fc8f53
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 197
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
Server: 1.0.6198.167 (rd_rdfe_stable.141203-1417) Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-servedbyregion: ussouth2
x-ms-request-id: 0a170e4e3f393e8aaadb8a82399d2ee3
Date: Mon, 08 Dec 2014 01:48:07 GMT

<Operation xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure" xmlns:i="http://www
.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><ID>997a9dad-cac5-3e43-a926-b36481fc8f53</ID><S
tatus>InProgress</Status></Operation>
C:\Users\gardam\preprodmgmtcert>curl -D - -E preprodazcert.pem -H "x-ms-version:
 2014-10-01" https://management.core.windows.net/04dc0d13-8d80-4781-b4b9-603708c
e871c/operations/997a9dadcac53e43a926b36481fc8f53
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 197
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
Server: 1.0.6198.167 (rd_rdfe_stable.141203-1417) Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-servedbyregion: ussouth2
x-ms-request-id: e78866b1e3c53bfc8d5313d4078f4f5f
Date: Mon, 08 Dec 2014 01:48:13 GMT

<Operation xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure" xmlns:i="http://www
.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><ID>997a9dad-cac5-3e43-a926-b36481fc8f53</ID><S
tatus>InProgress</Status></Operation>
C:\Users\gardam\preprodmgmtcert>curl -D - -E preprodazcert.pem -H "x-ms-version:
 2014-10-01" https://management.core.windows.net/04dc0d13-8d80-4781-b4b9-603708c
e871c/operations/997a9dadcac53e43a926b36481fc8f53
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 390
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
Server: 1.0.6198.167 (rd_rdfe_stable.141203-1417) Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-servedbyregion: ussouth2
x-ms-request-id: 8e552b9140ec34be90ab9c20e061d810
Date: Mon, 08 Dec 2014 01:49:45 GMT

<Operation xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure" xmlns:i="http://www
.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><ID>997a9dad-cac5-3e43-a926-b36481fc8f53</ID><S
tatus>Failed</Status><HttpStatusCode>409</HttpStatusCode><Error><Code>ConflictEr
ror</Code><Message>Windows Azure is currently performing an operation on this de
ployment that requires exclusive access.</Message></Error></Operation>
C:\Users\gardam\preprodmgmtcert>curl -D - -E preprodazcert.pem -H "x-ms-version:
 2014-10-01" https://management.core.windows.net/04dc0d13-8d80-4781-b4b9-603708c
e871c/operations/997a9dadcac53e43a926b36481fc8f53
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 390
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
Server: 1.0.6198.167 (rd_rdfe_stable.141203-1417) Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-servedbyregion: ussouth2
x-ms-request-id: 1efb6dc33c09374484f06550cb31661b
Date: Mon, 08 Dec 2014 01:50:03 GMT

<Operation xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure" xmlns:i="http://www
.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><ID>997a9dad-cac5-3e43-a926-b36481fc8f53</ID><S
tatus>Failed</Status><HttpStatusCode>409</HttpStatusCode><Error><Code>ConflictEr
ror</Code><Message>Windows Azure is currently performing an operation on this de
ployment that requires exclusive access.</Message></Error></Operation>
C:\Users\gardam\preprodmgmtcert>curl -D - -E preprodazcert.pem -H "x-ms-version:
 2014-10-01" https://management.core.windows.net/04dc0d13-8d80-4781-b4b9-603708c
e871c/operations/997a9dadcac53e43a926b36481fc8f53
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 390
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
Server: 1.0.6198.167 (rd_rdfe_stable.141203-1417) Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-servedbyregion: ussouth2
x-ms-request-id: 2d7a2cf3b043322083067519133d8e9d
Date: Mon, 08 Dec 2014 01:50:09 GMT

<Operation xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure" xmlns:i="http://www
.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><ID>997a9dad-cac5-3e43-a926-b36481fc8f53</ID><S
tatus>Failed</Status><HttpStatusCode>409</HttpStatusCode><Error><Code>ConflictEr
ror</Code><Message>Windows Azure is currently performing an operation on this de
ployment that requires exclusive access.</Message></Error></Operation>
```

The makevm.xml is given below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Deployment xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Name>testmevm1</Name>
  <DeploymentSlot>Production</DeploymentSlot>
  <Label>dGVzdG1ldm0x</Label>
  <RoleList>
    <Role>
      <RoleName>testmevm1</RoleName>
      <RoleType>PersistentVMRole</RoleType>
      <ConfigurationSets>
  <ConfigurationSet i:type="LinuxProvisioningConfigurationSet">
    <ConfigurationSetType>LinuxProvisioningConfiguration</ConfigurationSetType>
    <HostName>testmevm1</HostName>
    <UserName>devuser</UserName>
    <UserPassword>examplepassword</UserPassword>
    <DisableSshPasswordAuthentication>false</DisableSshPasswordAuthentication>
  </ConfigurationSet>
  <ConfigurationSet>
    <ConfigurationSetType>NetworkConfiguration</ConfigurationSetType>
    <InputEndpoints>
      <InputEndpoint>
        <LocalPort>22</LocalPort>
        <Name>SSH</Name>
        <Port>2222</Port>
        <Protocol>TCP</Protocol>
      </InputEndpoint>
      <InputEndpoint>
        <LocalPort>80</LocalPort>
        <Name>TCP-PORT-8080</Name>
        <Port>8080</Port>
        <Protocol>TCP</Protocol>
      </InputEndpoint>
      <InputEndpoint>
        <LocalPort>3389</LocalPort>
        <Name>TCP-PORT-3390</Name>
        <Port>3390</Port>
        <Protocol>TCP</Protocol>
      </InputEndpoint>
    </InputEndpoints>
    <SubnetNames>
      <SubnetName>us1-int-nb-app</SubnetName>
    </SubnetNames>
  </ConfigurationSet>
</ConfigurationSets>
      <AvailabilitySetName>us1-int-nb-app-avset1</AvailabilitySetName>
      <OSVirtualHardDisk>
  <HostCaching>ReadWrite</HostCaching>
  <DiskLabel>testmevm1-osdisk</DiskLabel>
  <DiskName>testmevm1-osdisk</DiskName>
  <MediaLink>http://demostg5.blob.core.windows.net/osdisk/disk_2014_12_07_17_08.vhd</MediaLink>
  <OS>Linux</OS>
  <RemoteSourceImageLink>https://us1preprodall.blob.core.windows.net/images/central-baseimage-os-2014-11-24.vhd</RemoteSourceImageLink>
</OSVirtualHardDisk>
      <RoleSize>Small</RoleSize>
    </Role>
  </RoleList>
  <VirtualNetworkName>us1-int</VirtualNetworkName>
</Deployment>
```

I have also submitted my qs to msdn azure forum but have got no clues / suggestions to help fix the issue im facing

Can someone please help?

regards

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are providing your own image. I believe the image and OS disk must be in the same storage account, which does not appear to be the case here.

Comment: Hi Neil, I was able to create vm in diff storage accounts using one centrally located image till wednesday of last week but since thursday I have been having issues. I am unable to understand why? Thank You

Comment: Hi Neil, Additionally I tried to create a vm from the image specified in the xml in the same storage account but a different container and im seeing the same issue.